# On what Stack Exchange site should I ask for programming related book recommendations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Sometimes I see questions on Stack Overflow like

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512666/what-is-the-best-book-or-site-to-learn-c-not-first-programming-language
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036492/what-is-the-best-book-to-study-c-net
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466749/best-erlang-book-references

and most of them are flagged as off topic, because they are not completely related to programming.

What are other Stack Exchange sites where these questions can be asked?

Comment: Nowhere. Such recommendation/shopping questions are off-topic for the entire network.

Comment: This type of question is generally not suitable for Stack Exchange - [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) blog post explains.

Comment: I am sorry, i am not getting your point, please elaborate it... Thanks

Comment: @Freedom There is no site within the network where such questions (book recommendations) can be asked. Read through the links we have provided you to see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and most of them are flagged as off topic, because they are not completely related to programming.

The ones you have listed are not closed as off topic. They are closed as *not constructive* and *duplicated* as they should.

Off topic marked question can indeed be suitable for other websites but if they are valid enough are usually moved to those websites. Sometimes though they are not suitable for the entire SE network *yet* and should stay closed.

> I want to ask about the other Stackexchange sites where these questions can be asked?

There are tons of [SE websites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) nowadays, but probably the most close to SO is [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Take a look at their [about page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about) and see if your questions are suitable for that website.

Notice that not constructive questions on SO are usually not suitable for the entire SE network due to their being *subjective*. Programmers in the other hand is known for being a little bit *softer* at accepting questions, but this is not the case.

Comment: Ahhh... Classic reason users should be careful how they edit their questions!